# how can I style specific cells of pandas df based on different df?

Tags: python, pandas

Considering the following two toy dataframes,

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,123,321], 'B':[0,1543,432], 'C': [10,20,30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,10,20], 'B':[50,43,42], 'C': [15,25,45]})
```

how can I set a given style for specific cells of `df1` in a jupyter notebook, based on `df2` (of the same size), by using the `subset` parameter?

For example, set these CSS values only if the corresponding `df2` cell value is above 40.

```
df1.style.set_properties(**{'color': 'red', 'font-size': '10px'})
                                #,subset= ???)
```

currently returning:

[image]

EDIT1: addressing a comment, the desired output should be the table above but the only cells with red font and 10 px font-size should be B0, B1, B2, and C2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `style.apply` with a reference dataframe and `axis=None`.

```
def highlight(df, ref_df=None, thresh=None):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(ref_df>thresh, 'color:red; font-size:13pt', ''),
                        index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

df1.style.apply(highlight, ref_df=df2, thresh=40, axis=None)
```

Output:

[image]